# Mostrar las habitaciones disponibles de acuerdo a dos fechas ingresadas(rangos)

Tags: mysql, sql

[image]

La idea es que ingresando la fecha de entrada y fecha de salida; mostrar las habitaciones disponibles comparando con las fechas reservas hechas.

Asumiendo las siguientes tablas y datos:

```
CREATE TABLE Habitaciones (
  habitacion_numero  INT
);

CREATE TABLE Reservas (
  habitacion     INT,
  inicio_fecha   DATE,
  fin_fecha   DATE
);

INSERT INTO Habitaciones (habitacion_numero)
VALUES (1),(2),(3),(4),(5);

INSERT INTO Reservas (habitacion, inicio_fecha, fin_fecha)
VALUES (1, '2017-12-01','2017-12-13'),
       (2, '2017-12-01','2017-12-10'),
       (2, '2017-12-12','2017-12-14'),
       (3, '2017-12-05','2017-12-08'),
       (3, '2017-12-15','2017-12-16'),
       (4, '2017-12-07','2017-12-11'),
       (5, '2017-12-03','2017-12-05');
```

...si ejecuto el SQL siguiente:

```
set @fecha1 = STR_TO_DATE('2017/12/09','%Y/%m/%d');
set @fecha2 = STR_TO_DATE('2017/12/11','%Y/%m/%d');

SELECT  h.habitacion_numero,
        CASE WHEN hr.habitacion_numero is null 
              THEN 'Disponible'
              ELSE 'Reservada'
        END  AS 'Estado'      
        FROM habitaciones h
        left JOIN (SELECT   h1.habitacion_numero
                      FROM habitaciones h1
                       inner join reservas r 
                       on h1.habitacion_numero=r.habitacion
                       WHERE @fecha BETWEEN r.inicio_fecha AND r.fin_fecha or 
                             @fecha2 BETWEEN r.inicio_fecha AND r.fin_fecha
                       AND r.fin_fecha
          ) hr
          on hr.habitacion_numero = h.habitacion_numero;
```

Obtengo el resultado erróneo siguiente:

```
habitacion_numero      Estado
-----------------      ------
        1              Reservada
        2              Disponible
        3              Disponible
        4              Reservada
        5              Disponible
```

El resultado es erróneo porque es obvio que la habitación 2 no está disponible con las fechas de entrada, por ejemplo.

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d631a8/20)

Comment: Hola davabun. Te felicito por incluir un fiddle, que raramente se ve. ¿Puedes por favor explicar cual es la diferencia entre la consulta/resultado en tu fiddle y lo que deseas obtener? ¿Qué es lo que falta?

Comment: Bueno la idea es mostrar las habitaciones si esta disponible o reservada; de acuerdo a un rango de dos fechas ingresado  comparandolo con las fechas de reserva de la BD, pero si analizas no esta comparando correctamene;si  @fecha1(2017/12/09) @fecha2(2017/12/11), la habitación 2 deberia estar "reservada", bueno puedes probar con otras fechas y te darás cuenta que no está comprando correctamene, espero su ayuda, gracias.

Comment: Lo que yo veo son 2 pequeños errores tipográficos. 1) Tienes un `AND r.fin_fecha` que sobra al final de la subconsulta, esto parece estar allí por error. 2) La consulta está usando la variable `@fecha` en vez de `@fecha1`. Prueba corrigiendo estos 2 errores menores y déjanos saber si aun tienes un problema. Fiddle con la consulta corregida: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d631a8/22. A mi me parece bien la consulta con estas 2 pequeñas correcciones.

Comment: Sigue sin hacer la comparación correctamene, mira por ejemplo en este rango  de fechas('2017/12/09' - 2017/12/19'), las habitaciones deberían estar reservadas, ya que todas incluyen el rango ingresado - [enlace](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d631a8/24/0)

Comment: Hmm. Tienes razón. La lógica de la consulta es incorrecta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como te dejé en los comentarios, tu consulta tiene 2 errores tipógraficos:

- Sobra la claúsula `AND r.fin_fecha` al final de la subconsulta
- Usas `@fecha` en vez de `@fecha1`

Con estas 2 correcciones, los resultados parecen correctos.  Pero en efecto, la lógica de la consulta no es correcta y seguirá produciendo resultados erróneos con otras fechas de entrada. De hecho, dependiendo de los datos, hasta es posible que te devuelva registros de habitaciones duplicadas debido a cómo funciona tu `LEFT JOIN`.

La consulta siguiente corrige la lógica que determina si las fechas de entrada se traslapan con alguna reservación para una habitación. Adicionalmente, uso la claúsula `EXISTS` para evitar duplicar los registros de habitaciones en caso que más de un registro en la tabla `reservas` se traslapa con las fechas de entrada:

```
set @fecha1 = STR_TO_DATE('2017/12/09','%Y/%m/%d');
set @fecha2 = STR_TO_DATE('2017/12/11','%Y/%m/%d');

SELECT  h.habitacion_numero,
        CASE WHEN hr.habitacion_numero is null 
              THEN 'Disponible'
              ELSE 'Reservada'
        END  AS Estado      
        FROM habitaciones h
        LEFT JOIN habitaciones hr
          ON hr.habitacion_numero = h.habitacion_numero
         AND EXISTS (
            SELECT NULL
              FROM reservas r
             WHERE r.habitacion = hr.habitacion_numero
               AND @fecha1 <= r.fin_fecha
               AND @fecha2 >= r.inicio_fecha
         )
order by h.habitacion_numero;
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/1e24f2/2)

---

Y de paso, si solo necesitas la lista de habitaciones disponibles, en vez de la lista completa de habitaciones con el estado `Disponible` o `Reservada`, como lo tienes ahora, entonces puedes simplificar la consulta:

```
SELECT h.habitacion_numero
  FROM habitaciones h
 WHERE NOT EXISTS (
         SELECT NULL
           FROM reservas r
          WHERE r.habitacion = h.habitacion_numero
            AND @fecha1 <= r.fin_fecha
            AND @fecha2 >= r.inicio_fecha)
 ORDER BY h.habitacion_numero;
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/1e24f2/14)

Comment: Gracias por el apoyo, @sstan